# OWASP Regular expression for file path in java not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, validation, path, owasp

The below is the OWASP regular expression which i'm using to validate the File paths. but it's not working as expected. please find the below details.

Regular expression for

```
file path = "^[a-zA-Z0-9:/\\\\!@#$%^&{}\\[\\]()_+\\-=,.~'` ]{1,255}$";
Input1 = "E:\Hello\One\FilePath1\";
Input2 = "E:\Hello\One\1FilePath\";
```

The regular expression for file path works for Input1 and not for Input2. The reason is in Input2 after slash \ immediately if digit comes it's failing the validation. Can somebody please help on this pattern modification.

Thank you :)

Comment: Both inputs are accepted using an online tester.  What makes you think it's not working?  Maybe the problem is in your test code.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. it will work in java file if we provide directly in java file with escape sequence. And sorry forgot to add some more information in the beginning. actually i have provided this regular expression pattern in properties file. so when it comes to java file it's coming as "^[a-zA-Z0-9:/\\!@#$%^&{}\[\]()_+\-=,.~'` ]{1,255}$". One more info the path allowing if i put digit after forward slash / but it's not working if i put digit after back ward slash. thank you.

Comment: There isn't a problem with the code you've posted, so there is a problem with the code you haven't posted.  Please update the code in the question so that it reproduces the problem you say you are seeing.

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply. There is no issue with java code as u  know. I am using ESAPI library class's validInput() method to validate the file paths. But this method is not allowing octal characters that's where the issue exists. So i have removed this ESAPI library class's method for file path validations alone. And then my issue got resolved. Thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Yes, you need to double-backslash string literals

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue myself. There is no issue with java code here. I am using ESAPI library class's built-in validInput() method to validate the file paths. But this method is not allowing octal characters that's where the issue exists.

So i have removed this ESAPI library class's method for file path validations alone. And then i added a customized method.